# what was the name of girl who gives everyone starfish in clannad?

Tags: clannad

i really cannot recall hear. what was her name again? Since this post does not meet standards i have to write that i tried to remember her but no luck in this.

Comment: Fuuko's spiritual power is stronger then that!

Comment: You forgot her? You're the worst...

Answer (score 8):

The character's name is *Fuko Ibuki*, sometimes spelt *Fuuko*

[image]

You probably could have Googled 'starfish girl Clannad' to get the answer faster